# WordPress plugin with Nodejs and Socket.io

Tags: node.js, wordpress, socket.io

I need some advice from you guys.

I need to create WordPress chat plugin with Socket.io .  But socket.io need a nodejs server to run. My problem is most of WordPress user's don't have servers that can run nodejs and also most of hosting packages are manged hosting.

So I found that there are some libraries called socket io php emitter. But for those also they need some php extensions that most severs don't have by default to function.

I'm sure there must be a way to do this. Since we have REST API and WordPress doing lot of things with ReactJS etc. I'm open to anything.  I just need a chat plugin developed using javascript. I'm open to use any js framework like Angular, React.  But I don't know how to use those with WordPress plugins.

If I can't do this with js, I'm ok to use PHP instead. Please let me know your thoughts. Please give me some directions.

Thanks

Comment: How about creating a subdomain that will run the nodejs server and then using an iframe to load the chat on the client side via Wordpress?

Comment: @Nadav well the thing is, this plugin is not just for one site. People will be able to download it form WordPress plugin directory.  Features must work just activating the plugin. This plugin also need to work like other plugins.

Comment: @DhanukaNuwan If I may ask, did you find a suitable solution in the last 6 months? I have quite the same situation right now (a Wordpress based site with a finished frontend, need to enable socket.io communication to a node.js/Express based REST API) and was wondering what your approach to this task was.